# No new class instance created after calling new class() within a jest test

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, node-redis

### Issue

Creating new class instance within unit test does not trigger the constructor.

---

### Details

I am trying to test if an error is thrown when the wrong server IP is given, however when I try to create a new instance of the class that should throw the error it does not work.

The class I am trying to test is:

```ts
export class ClassA {
    private readonly _redisServerIP = config.redisServerIP;
    private readonly _redisServerPort = config.redisServerPort;

    constructor() {
        console.log(this._redisServerIP);
        this.configure();
    }

    private configure(): void {
        this._redisSub = redis.createClient({host: this._redisServerIP, port: this._redisServerPort});

        this._redisSub.on('error', (error) => {
            if (error.code === "ECONNREFUSED") {
                this._logger.error('Could not create a redisSub, is the redis server running?');
            }
            throw new Error('Something bad happened');
        });
    }
}
```

This is my test code:

```ts
import * as constants from '../src/config/config';

let socket;
let classA;
let httpServerAddr;

beforeAll((done) => {
classA = new ClassA();
    httpServerAddr = classA.getServerIp();
    done();
});

afterAll((done) => {
    done();
});

beforeEach((done) => {

});

afterEach((done) => {
    done();
});

describe('Socket.io redis testing', () => {
    test('should fail due to invalid serverIP', () => {
        constants.config.redisServerIP = "0.0.0.0";
        classA = null;

        expect(() => {
            classA = new ClassA();
        }).toThrow();
    });
});
```

I only see the server ip once in my node console and the test fails due to the following error:

```ts
expect(function).toThrow(undefined)
Expected the function to throw an error.
But it didn't throw anything.
```

Is this because every test runs in it's own promise? And when it's running in that said promise it can't log to the console? Or is it because of me not clearing the existing instance of ClassA before calling new ClassA()?

**======EDIT======**

After using breakpoints I figured out that the constructor is called, it however does not write to the console. But the throw never happens, how redis works is; if it has an error, an event is send to the redis server with the name "error", this does not get triggered when running the test, how could one wait for that to trigger?

Comment: It's async; calling new doesn't cause an exception, the eventual callback does.

Comment: That makes sense, how does one go about testing that? I tried making my test async and added await infront of my expect, but it still does not trigger.

Comment: There's nothing to `await`; there are no promises involved anywhere. You could make the class instantiation synchronous (which makes some sense in this case, depending on how you actually want to use it, since if there's no Redis instance available, you'd need to handle it). So you could simply wrap the events in promises, await in the ctor, problem solved.

Comment: Isn't that a bit dirty? Sadly, there is no other way to detect if the redis connection failed, but wrapping it around promises and then awaiting in my constructor surely is not the only way to solve this?

Comment: Of course it isn't. From the app's point of view it probably makes the most sense, but that doesn't mean you have to do it that way--you already have a race condition where you don't have any way of knowing if the Redis connection has been made successfully before you can use the class, so if you don't care about that, there's no reason to wait. You can handle it the exact same way you'd handle it in your app then, by either waiting for time, polling over time, etc. Personally I would either wrap it in your own events or promises so you don't have to just guess, but YMMV.

Comment: Thank you for your help thus far, I tried using promises around the redis client, but for some reason it still does not wait for it. I think it's because I call it within the contructor therefore it does not wait for it(which is obvious), what do you mean with own events? Could you elaborate please?

Comment: Promises don't care of they're in a constructor. You can emit your own app-specific events, e.g., a "redisReasy" or "redisError" event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by making the redisSub public, and calling a process.exit(); when the connection failed, in the unit-test I spyOn process.exit() and check if it has been called.

This is the test code:

```ts
describe('Socket.io redis testing', () => {
    test('should fail due to invalid serverIP', () => {
        const mockExit = jest.spyOn(process, 'exit').mockImplementation(() => {});

        constants.config.redisServerIP = "127.312.12.1";

        classA.stopServer();
        classA = null;
        classA = new ClassA();

        classA.redisSub.on('error', () => {
            expect(mockExit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
        });
        mockExit.mockRestore();
    });
```

Although the use of events within ClassA would have worked as well, I did not think that was the most elegant solution.